# Android ValueAnimator Sin wave

Tags: android, translate-animation

I've got a Custom ViewGroup class and an image I've added to it. When the screen is tapped I want to animate the added image to travel across the screen in a wavelike pattern. What I have now is below but though the image moves in a wavelike pattern it jumps around too quickly and is a blur. How can I slow it down to move in a steady wave?

```
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1); // values from 0 to 1
    if(animateImage) {
        incrementalValue = 0f;
        animator.setDuration(4000);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()))
                        .floatValue();
                float amplitude = 100f;
                mImage.setTranslationX(incrementalValue);
                mImage.setTranslationY((float) (amplitude * Math.sin((incrementalValue) * Math.PI)));
                 incrementalValue += 5f;
            }
        });
        animator.setTarget(mImage);
        animator.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a float `value` in `onAnimationUpdate` and never use it again. The calcualtion for the image translation is `mImage.setTranslationY((float) (amplitude * Math.sin((incrementalValue) * Math.PI)));`. If you insert the values and `incrementalValue` ( = 0) doesn't change, this calculation will always return 0 because sin(0) = 0 and one 0 in a multiplication makes the product 0. You  should insert `animator.getAnimatedValue` for `incrementalValue`. Besides, i suggest you change the calculation to `sin(animator.getAnimatedValue()*PI*2)` this makes the wavelength of the sine  1[image: sin(x*pi*2)] and the image will move up and down once per repetition of the animation and it won't jump when the aimation restarts.

**Note** you can still multiply with amplitude to make the image move a certain distance.

Comment: Thank you that works great! The only thing I changed was mImage.setTranslationX(value + incrementalValue); instead of mImage.setTranslation(incrementalValue). Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: So you want the image to move sideways and up and down? Btw how about an upvote :D

Comment: Without the setTranslationX statement in my comment above the image moves up and down but doesn't travel across the screen. With it though it does move in a sin wave pattern. And yes you definitely get an upvote :)